# Addsubview on certain page of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

My app dynamically creates buttons on the screen, and I have a setup where it adds a new "page" to the scrollview when the number of buttons on one screen hits a certain amount.

How do I access a specific page of the scroll view that is newly created?

I want to be able to put the next button on the next page of the view.

My simple conditional:

```
if (numberOfButtons % 12 == 0) {        
    numberOfViews++;
    [self createView];
     numberOfViews++;
    [self createView];
    [self.containerView addSubview:button]    
}
```

How my view is generated (createView):

```
-(void)createView {
    int multiplier  = numberOfViews;
    NSLog(@"Views: %i",multiplier);
    for (int i = 0; i < multiplier; i++) {        
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.containerView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.containerView.frame.size;
        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        [viewCount addObject:subview];
        subview.backgroundColor = self.containerView.backgroundColor;
        [self.containerView addSubview:subview];
    }

    self.containerView.contentSize = 
                             CGSizeMake(self.containerView.frame.size.width * multiplier,
                                           self.containerView.frame.size.height);

    [containerView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(numberOfViews*320,0)];
        NSLog(@"View Created!");

}
```

If it helps, "self.containerview" is my Scroll View object that lives in my ViewController.

Comment: please remove these lines `[viewCount addObject:subview];
        subview.backgroundColor = self.containerView.backgroundColor;` it doesn't add anything to the question

Comment: also what does `[self.containerView addSubview:drawer]` do? what is `drawer`? what is viewCount? in general.. please don't put dead end variables in your code.. your code should be as concise as possible.. otherwise it leads people trying to help you to dead ends.

Comment: sorry, it's a UIButton, thought I edited them all out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create paging in a scrollview.. a very common UI problem that tonnes of people before you and after you will face.. whenever you're faced by such a problem.. the first thing you should do is see if there is an existing library that does the grunt work for you.

Fortunately.. there are several reliable libraries that solve precisely this problem. I use [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20), which has a [TTScrollView](http://chromeworld2.appspot.com/api.Three20.info/interface_t_t_scroll_view.php) class that handles scrollview paging.

A common complaint about three20 is it's extremely lacking documentation.. fortunately for you, there is a much better documented alternative for three20 called [nimbus](http://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus), and which also has a [paging scrollview class](http://docs.nimbuskit.info/NimbusPagingScrollView.html). I strongly recommend you check these guys out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out. However, are there any complications that will play in when I sell my app that uses these libraries?

Comment: Do mean legal complications? Absolutely not.. It's open source and is used by many applications already sold on the app store.. I'm currently using it myself without any problems

Comment: but seriously.. you should get used to the habit of using open source in your projects (including those you intend to publish in the app store).. otherwise u'll be spending countless hours doing things that are already implemented.. check this site out for example: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/

Comment: If it's very helpful u should prolly give me the right award or a vote up at least lol

Answer (score 0):

for displaying  particuler page in scrollview you can use `setContentOffset` method  for scrollview.

```
[scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageIndex*320,0) animated:YES];//if horizantal Scroll scroll
```

Comment: interesting, thanks for the tip. Would I call this method in the function where I create the objects or in the createView function itself? I'm guessing I'll have to set the offset in my conditional, and then addSubview?

Comment: based on your requirement you can place this one in your method and pass correct pageindex value it's an integer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I've added the lines of code represented in my latest edit to the original post. This is great, because it actually scrolls to the next page when I fulfill the conditional, but it does not add the next object to the screen. It keeps adding it to the bottom of the first one. Thoughts? EDIT: Also used 640 to multiply the pageIndex by (iPhone retina whatever), still did not work

Comment: if possible show me screen shot of that one im not getting clearly wt you are saying?

Comment: Sure! The buttons that are in the red box are ones that should stay in the current view, while the ones in the green box should be align themselves similarly as the first view, but on the next page. Let me know if additional clarification is needed. http://i.imgur.com/y1Kf771.png

Comment: Images are not displayed because of the slow internet.

Comment: resized it to 50%, how's this? http://www.picresize.com/popup.html?images/rsz_screen_shot_2013-05-24_at_112908_pm.png